# How to preview an HTML file in Kindle for PC?

Tags: kindle

I have the task of preparing an HTML file that will be used in a Kindle ebook. I would like to preview this HTML file in Kindle to see how it translates fonts and images.

Is this possible using Amazon Kindle for PC? Or are there other emulators out there?

The Kindle emulator Amazon provide in Amazon DTP actually looks terrible. I hope Kindles don't really interpret HTML like the Amazon provided emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I've been able to gather it appears that Kindle for PC is your best (or unfortunately for you worst) case of an emulator out there.  There is a Kindle Developer's Kit (KDK) that you can sign up and request to be a part of.  From their [site](https://kindlepublishing.amazon.com/gp/vendor/sign-in/183-1941791-0271100?ie=UTF8&originatingURI=/gp/vendor/members/kindlepubs/kdk/home):

> To become a part of the KDK limited beta, request to become a beta developer. Accepted beta participants will be able to download the Kindle Development Kit, access developer support, test content on Kindle, and submit finished content. Those wait-listed will be invited to participate at a later date as space becomes available. The Kindle Development Kit includes sample code, documentation, and the Kindle Simulator, which helps developers build and test their content by simulating the 6-inch Kindle and 9.7-inch Kindle DX device on Mac, PC, and Linux desktops. Content submission is free during limited beta.